# Asymmetric distribution where the mean equals the median

Tags: probability

This is a problem that has been bugging me. Are there examples of asymmetric probability distributions with continuous density function where the mean equals the median and both equal 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to find two different distributions with positive support and the same mean, then compose a piecewise PDF where one of the distributions is made to have negative support. For example, 1) a log-normal distribution with parameters $\mu=-1$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{2}$, and 2) an inverse-gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha=2$ (shape) and $\beta=1$ (scale).

Let $f(x)\neq g(x)$ be PDFs with support $x>0$ and

$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}g(x)<\infty$$
$$\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx=\int_0^\infty xg(x)dx$$

The distribution with PDF

$$\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{2}f(|x|) & x<0 \\
      \frac{1}{2}g(x) & x>0
   \end{cases}$$

would be asymmetric, continuous, and have a mean and median both equal to 0.

Comment: Thank you very much